# Script Task in SSIS not work

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I working with SSIS then I have some problem about see this image below

[image]

When I run this Package on visual studio 2010 it's run and stop at Data Flow task it's not run script task but when I try use 1 script task for 1 input flow it's run script task

So, Why my script task not run when many input flow and how to fix it

Thank you.

Comment: You do not provide any error messages.  Have you stepped through the code in the script task to see where is is failing?

Comment: Thank you for response @BobF

I will found solution I set MaximumErrorCount more than 1 it's solve my problem

Comment: Does that not just move the issue down the road so to speak?  That is you still have an issue, the system will now just ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will found solution I set MaximumErrorCount more than 1 it's solve my problem